# I need some clarification regarding functions.

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = 3 + 5$ and $() = 4^2 − 2$, find:

1. $(g(3))$
2. $g(3)$

Would you get the same answer for one and two? I think I read or heard somewhere that it doesn't matter whether you put a function within brackets or not.

I want to be *absolutely* sure because I'm not exactly a math genius.

Comment: I guess majority of the times you are right, except if you define $fg$ as pointwise multiplication. Just to elaborate a little more, $fg$ can be composition of functions then you are right; or if $fg$ is defined as pointwise-multiplication then you would be wrong.

Comment: Who is asking you these questions, and how did they define their terms?  There can definitely be a difference between what f(g(x)) and fg(x) means.

Comment: My math teacher. I vaguely remembered him telling the class but I wanted to confirm whether I heard him correctly or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, those are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ambiguous to write $fg(3)$, because it could either mean $$(f\circ g)(3) = f(g(3))$$ or it could be a sloppy way of writing $$(fg)(3)= f(3)\cdot g(3),$$ and these two things are not generally the same:
$$
(fg)(3) = f(g(3)) = f(30) = 95$$
whereas
$$f(3)\cdot g(3) = 14\cdot 30 = 420$$

If this is given in an assignment it's probably best to ask your instructor what they mean.  If you are looking for a shorter way of writing $f(g(3))$ you should go with $(f\circ g)(3)$